# Working with where clauses inside views

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, view, parameter-passing

```
CREATE VIEW summary AS  
SELECT sales.inventory_id,
       sum(sales.value) AS value,
       count(sales.*) AS sales_n,
FROM promotion
JOIN sales USING (promotion_id)
GROUP BY sales.inventory_id
;
```

1. This is a simplified query of a problem that I am dealing with
2. However, I would like to be able to add a `WHERE` clause into the view. Something like this `WHERE promotion.created_at > ?`

QUESTION:

How should I modify the view so that I can do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM summary 
WHERE promotion.created_at > [timestamp]
```

I am currently not able to do this because there is a `GROUP BY` on `inventory_id` so `promotion.created_at` is not captured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an **SQL function** taking the timestamp as parameter instead:

```
CREATE FUNCTION summary(_created_at timestamp)
  RETURNS TABLE (inventory_id int, value bigint, sales_n int)
AS
$func$
SELECT s.inventory_id
     , sum(s.value) -- AS value  -- alias not visible outside function
     , count(*)     -- AS sales_n
FROM   promotion p
JOIN   sales     s USING (promotion_id)
WHERE  p.created_at > $1
GROUP  BY s.inventory_id
$func$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM summary('2014-06-01 10:00');
```

I shortened the syntax with table aliases.
`count(*)` does the same as `count(s.*)` here.
Adapt `RETURNS TABLE(...)` to your actual data types.